# Is there a poster plugin for videogular2?

Tags: angular, videogular

I am working on videogular2 api to play the videos in my application. I see there is a poster plugin for **videogular**. But I didn't find it for **videogular2**. Can someone please point me in the right direction if you have came across this.

Answer (score 4):

There is `poster` attribute for `video` tag which you just set with path to image. An example:

```
<video #media [vgMedia]="media" [src]="video.src" id="modalPlayer" 
    "preload="auto" [poster]="video.poster">
</video>
```

Comment: There is a poster plugin for videoagular 1 that auto generates a poster image.  I believe this is what @murail101002 is looking for (and how I ended up on this thread as well.)

Answer (score 0):

For every people like me who was searching a `vg-poster` tag and didn't want to work with the `post` attribute.

- videogular does not have recreate vg-poster since it is already implemented within the html `video` tag. https://github.com/videogular/videogular2/issues/734#issuecomment-393447626
- You could also:
  *write a very simple "vg-poster" element, subscribe through the API to play/pause events and hide show this element however you would like.* @kwarismian
  found here https://github.com/videogular/videogular2/issues/748#issuecomment-403524060